# Breaking on to new lines?

Tags: coding-standards

If I have a long line of code that exceeds 80 characters, like this:

```
$last_response = '<strong>' . t('Last response: ') . '</strong>' . format_interval((time() - $last), 1) . t(' ago');
```

Should I break it on to a new line and indent once? I'm sure I've read this in the coding standards somewhere, but now I cannot find where I read it, if I did, like this.

```
$last_response = '<strong>' . t('Last response: ') . '</strong>'
  . format_interval((time() - $last), 1) . t(' ago');
```

Comment: check the comment by sun https://drupal.org/node/935284#comment-4590004

Comment: Say you were submitting a patch, I don't think anyone would care either way in this case. IMO it is whatever is most readable depending on the particular code you are writing, keeping comments to 80 or less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, you should break and indent.

For the more details, including exceptions to this rule, see the official Drupal coding standards on [line length and wrapping](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#linelength) and [indenting](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#indenting).

A handy tool to check whether your source code follow the official Drupal codings standards is [Coder](https://drupal.org/project/coder).  It is also available as SaaS, as part of [PAreview](http://pareview.sh/pareview).